# Hammer.js momentum, velocity, throw behavior

Tags: javascript, touch, hammer.js

I want to implement a Pan behavior with momentum using Hammerjs. Basically, after the touch event ends the scrolling should continue, starting at the final velocity, easing out, and stopping.

I have found an old version of the Github Readme on a forked version of Hammer.js: https://github.com/visiongeist/hammer.js

Which talks about a "Momentum" or "Drag/Throw experience" which has a broken link to: http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/momentum/

And I've searched the documentation on http://hammerjs.github.io/ thoroughly but cannot find any references.

I know I could implement this manually using a custom gesture, but I really feel like there should be a very simple, built-in way to do this without all the fuss.

Can someone shine a light on this please? Thanks!